# Trying to use upstart to run npm script, but can't find where npm is installed

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm, upstart, nvm

I started an Amazon Linux instance via AWS EC2. I'm trying to write an upstart script that will start my node server when the instance starts up.

If I run `npm start` in the terminal, my node server starts successfully. I'm using the following upstart script, but it doesn't start my server.

```
# Upstart Script for My Server
description "my-server"

start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

# Automatically Respawn
respawn
respawn limit 99 5

# Environment Variables
env NODE_ENV=development

# Script to Start Server
script
  cd /home/ec2-user/my-server
  exec /usr/bin/npm start >> /var/log/my-server.log 2>&1
end script
```

Checking the `/var/log/my-server.log` file tells me `/user/bin/npm: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Why use upstart (which has been largely abandoned now) instead of systemd/monit/pm2/etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

My issue was due to the fact that I had [installed node using NVM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html) (Node Version Manager). NPM was not installed in my `/user/bin` directory. I just needed to find where it was installed by NVM.

```
# Script to Start Server
# - Referencing 'npm' from Node Version Manager (NVM) install location.
script
  cd /home/ec2-user/my-server
  exec /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/bin/npm start >> /var/log/my-server.log 2>&1
end script
```